# ActionLink button to change multiple parts of the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have A button of `BtnNext()` that when click will Dequeue the items the I Enqueue. I use Tempdata so that I can use the Dequeued data and render it on my view.

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult BtnNext()
{
    var first = MyQueue.todayQueue.Dequeue();
    MyQueue.todayQueue.Count();
    TempData["QueueItem"] = first;
    return View();
}
```

Here is my view:

```
    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null, new { @class = @cssClass, @id = "Link1" })
```

***I expect this button to behave like this.***
When I click this button it will refresh the page and render the Dequeued data in the same view just change A portion of my view with the dequeued property

Right now what this code is doing when I click the `BtnNext()`  the error is its trying to find A view with url like this `http://localhost:50000/TellerScreens/BtnNext` but I don't want it to go to another page, I just want to update a portion of the Index so the url must stay
`http://localhost:50000/TellerScreens`

Comment: In your `BtnNext()`: return `View("TellerScreens");`

Comment: User partial view which will get udpated when you raise the particular request.